# Solve congruence $x^2+x+9\equiv 0 \pmod{63}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

$x^2+x+9\equiv 0 \pmod{63}$

I know that $63=3^2 \cdot7$, so I try to solve like this $x^2+x+9\equiv 0 \pmod 9$ and $x^2+x+9\equiv 0 \pmod 7$, from first equation  $x^2+x \equiv -9  \pmod 9 $,$x^2+x \equiv 0  \pmod 9 $, then I find that $x=9m+2$ and $x^2=9k+7$, or $x=9m+5$ and $x^2=9k+4$ or $x=9m+8$ and $x^2=9k+1$, the same for $7$ but it does not help me, then I multiply 63 until I do not get a square equation that I can solve, so I then I get $x^2+x+9=315$ from here $x_1=-18$ and $x_2=17$, but is there some other way to do this?

Comment: $9$ and $7$ are small enough for you to try all possible $x$. Alternatively, you can complete the square.

Comment: There's easier way. $x^2+x = x(x+1)$, that's two co-prime numbers, so $9$ must divide only one of them. So $x\equiv 0 \,\lor\,x\equiv -1 \pmod9$. For $\mod7$ you might notice that $x^2-6x+9\equiv 0\pmod7$ and complete the square.

Answer (score 2):

The congruence $x^2+x+9\equiv 0\pmod 9$ simplifies to $$x^2+x=x(x+1)\equiv 0\pmod 9. $$
Calculating for all values of $x\bmod 9$, it is easy to check there are two solutions.

Modulo $7$, the congruence becomes
$$x^2+x+2\equiv 0.$$
As we're in a field, you may calculate the discriminant, which happens to be $0\bmod 7$. So there is a double root, which has to be a root of the derivative, so it satisfies the equation
$$2x+1\equiv 0\pmod 7.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to $7|x^2+x-12=(x+4)(x-3)\land 9|x(x+1)$, i.e. $7|x-3\land (9|x\lor 9|x+1)$, i.e. $63|x-45\lor 63|x-17$.